# What's the link from $2^u-1$ to the multiplicative order?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues, primality-test

I am reading [this paper](https://www.math.ru.nl/%7Ebosma/pubs/MathComp1993.pdf), but I will write everyting I need for my question here.
So, long story short, we have a proth-number $n$, i.e. $n = h\cdot 2^k+1$ for odd $h<2^k$.
We are looking for integers $D$ such that the Jacobi symbol
$$
\left(\frac{D}{n}\right) \neq 1.
$$
I could already prove that
$$ \left(\frac{D}{n}\right) = \left(\frac{n}{D}\right),$$
so we can reduce $n \pmod D$.
Now I know that
$$ h\cdot 2^k+1  \equiv (h\pmod D)\cdot 2^{k\mod ord_p(2)}\pmod D,$$
where $ord_p(2)$ is the order of $2$ modulo $D$.
So of course we are interested in finding a $D$ with a possibly low order, because if $D$ is a solution for a $k$, then it's a solution for every $k\pmod{ord_p(2)}$.
What I do not understand is this: In (4.1) of the paper, they say:
[image: this here]

But I do not get the link. Why is it useful to factorize $2^u-1$?

Comment: Please, use descriptive titles. "Problems understanding a paper" says nothing about the subject of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any prime $D$ that divides $2^u-1$ satisfies $2^u-1\equiv 0\pmod D$, which means that $2^u\equiv 1\pmod D$, i.e. $\mathrm{ord}_p(2)\mid u$.

Comment: I see, thank you. So, is this "just" a way to determine the order of 2 mod prime p? (The paper is from 1993)

Comment: More precisely, it is a way to find _all_ primes for which $2$ has order $u$, because for all prime factors of $2^u-1$ the multiplicative order of 2 is $u$ (or smaller), and any prime $D$ for which $2^u\equiv1\pmod D$ must be a factor of $2^u-1$.

Comment: Do you maybe mean at most $u$? Because $2^{10}-1 = 3\cdot 11\cdot 31$ and the orders are $2,10,5$.